# Multiple nested group with single regex pattern

Tags: regex

**Hello**
I'm trying to create a regex to format a message sent to players, in this case in Minecraft.
For those familiar with Minecraft, and the API will be aware of the TextComponent, with hover events and clickable messages.
But for this question, any knowledge of Minecraft is irrelevant, as I only ask about regex groups.

I have a handler, which builds a message, based on a String.
Users have the option to use HTML like tags to create very customizable messages, that shows some text when hovering over them with a mouse, and perform an action when clicked.

I have the following two base tags:

```
<hover action="The text that shows when hovered">The message sent in the chat</hover>
<click type="command" action="The command run when clicked">The message sent in the chat</click>
```

The `action` in both tags can be completely customized.
The `type` in the click tag can be following: `command`, `suggest` and `url`.
There may however be support for more tags, and therefore I capture it with `type="(.*?)"`

**Example strings**:

```
// Simple string. One hover for entire message, and individual click actions
<hover action="Click on either [Accept] or [Deny] to answer the duel">Click here to answer the duel: <click type="command" action="/duel accept">[Accept]</click> <click type="command" action="/duel deny">[Deny]</click></hover>

// More advanced string. There is 3 different hover events, and still the 2 click events
<hover action="Click on either [Accept] or [Deny] to answer the duel">Click here to answer the duel:</hover> <click type="command" action="/duel accept"><hover action="Click here to accept">[Accept]</hover></click> <click type="command" action="/duel deny"><hover action="Click here to deny">[Deny]</hover></click>
```

At the moment I can capture the **hover** and **click** group individually with following two regexes

```regex
// Capture the click groups
(?i)<click type="(.*?)" action="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/click>

// Capture the hover groups
(?i)<hover action="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/hover>
```

[Click regex example](https://regex101.com/r/9u9jJq/1) (regex101.com)
[Hover regex example](https://regex101.com/r/0hutzF/1) (regex101.com)
These two regexes capture everything perfectly.
The problem I have is I need to put them together to one regex, supporting nested groups.
If we take the first example String, it should capture the entire hover event, but also the two click events.
The same with the second string. I need it to capture all three hover and the two click events.
The groups should be captured in the order they appear, like following

```
// String 1
Match 1: Hover
Match 2: Click
Match 3: Click

//String 2
Match 1: Hover
Match 2: Click
Match 3: Hover
Match 4: Click
Match 5: Hover
```

I've tried putting the two regex together with a simple or operator (`|`) like following:
`(?i)(<hover action="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/hover>|<click type="(.*?)" action="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/click>)`
This however only only returns `hover` in the first string, and `hover`, `click`, `click` in the second string, meaning it does not get nested capture groups.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: are trying to build a structure of multi-level nesting ?

Comment: for a linear top down and donnot care about nesting just match either _<hover..>_ or _<click..>_ open tags, whay care about close thags

Comment: > are trying to build a structure of multi-level nesting ?      
@Edward For hower and click events, there can be multi level nesting.  
A single event should not be nested, so a `hover` event should end before a new one start, but there can be `click` events inside the `hover` event.  

The same for `click` events, there can be `hover` multiple hover events inside, but 
not other `click` events

-----------------
> why care about close tags  
So I know where to end my hover event, ensuring the rest of the message does not have the event (same with click)

Comment: k, so want to match click +many hovers  or hover +many clicks , yes?

Comment: Yes, both of those. The order is unknown, as the users can do as they wish. :)

Comment: I´m using https://regex101.com/ to test

Comment: the overall captures can be broken down for sub clicks or huverss, it easy regex

Answer (score 0):

Try `(<click(?=\s)[^>]*?>(?:(?!<click(?=\s))[\S\s])*?</click\s*>)|(<hover(?=\s)[^>]*?>(?:(?!<hover(?=\s))[\S\s])*?</hover\s*>)`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/4GYVrM/1)

feature:

- group 1 match have a click block
- group 2 match have a hover block
- will not allow a nesting of same block tag ie. click click /click /click, etc...

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not get the nested inner groups.
In the first string, I get the whole thing, as it is fully surrounded by hover, and not the hover in one group, and the hover in two other groups-